# ng-show not watching variable change

Tags: angularjs

I have a progress bar I want to show after I click a button.
I set my variable to true on click, yet it's not working.

The ng-show in question is on the bottom of the html, and the button i click is on a different html page but i didn't include because it uses the successOnClick function in this same controller. I console logged the isEmailing variable inside the onclick and it is assigned true. Doesn't work for ng-if either

What gives?

```js
module.exports = app => {
    app.controller('ContactController', ($scope, $http) => {
        $scope.isEmailing = false;

        $scope.email = (e) => {
            $scope.isEmailing = true;

            const requestBody = {};
            const id = e.target.id;
            requestBody.name = document.getElementById(`${id}-name`).value;
            requestBody.email = document.getElementById(`${id}-email`).value;
            requestBody.subject = document.getElementById(`${id}-subject`).value;
            requestBody.body = document.getElementById(`${id}-body`).value;

            $http.post('/email', JSON.stringify(requestBody), {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                })
                .then(res => {
                    console.log('Success!');
                    document.getElementById(`${id}-name`).value = '';
                    document.getElementById(`${id}-email`).value = '';
                    document.getElementById(`${id}-subject`).value = '';
                    document.getElementById(`${id}-body`).value = '';
                    $scope.isEmailing = false;
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log('Error!');
                    $scope.isEmailing = false;
                })
        }

        $scope.successOnClick = () => {
            $scope.isEmailing = true;
        }
    })
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer" ng-controller="ContactController">
    <div class="footer__block social-media-container">
        <div class="social-media">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Absolute-Zero-Polar-Cooler-Bag-for-Work-Golf-Picnics-Travel-and-More-258801584535251/"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/bVqv5Kk.png" alt="fb-icon"></a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/absolutezerobag"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/sJWiCHV.png" alt="twitter-icon"></a>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/absolutezerobags/"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/o7yTVyL.png" alt="insta-icon"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer__block">
        <form class="footer__form" ng-submit="email($event)" id="footer">
            <textarea placeholder="Message" id="footer-body" required></textarea>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="footer-name" required>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" id="footer-email" required>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Subject" id="footer-subject" required>
            <input type="submit" placeholder="Email">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="footer__block mailing-list">
        <span>Join our Mailing List!</span>
        <form>
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="grey-screen">
          <div class="success">
            <h1>Success!</h1>
          </div>
        </div> -->
    <div class="progress-bar" ng-show="isEmailing">
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Why do you think, that method call at **different html page** will reflect on this `ng-show`? They not connected at all. You definitely should show, how you call `successOnClick`.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov Ok I see the problem, but not sure why this is the case. I have the same controller on two different sections and changing variables from one section for some reason the ng-show will not update on the other section even though the variable indeed changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have several controller of same type it is not mean, that they all are same the instance. AngularJS creates controllers not via singleton pattern. You should synchronize them by yourself by means of events:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('Changed', function(event, data){
      $scope.isEmailing = data;
    })
    
    $scope.successOnClick = function(){
      $scope.$emit('Changed', !$scope.isEmailing);
    }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <h3 ng-style="{'background-color' : isEmailing ? 'red' : 'white'}">First controller</h3>
    <input type='button' ng-click='successOnClick()' value='Change color'/>        
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    <h3 ng-style="{'background-color' : isEmailing ? 'red' : 'white'}">Second controller</h3>
    <input type='button' ng-click='successOnClick()' value='Change color'/>    
  </div>
</div>
```

If one controller located inside another you can try to use `$scope.$parent.isEmailing`(where `.$parent` can be typed several times, depending on nesting level), but it is very uncomfortable. If your controllers located at different routes, you should pass data from one controler to another via route parameters or custom AngularJS service or `$rootScope`.